# jQuery to check state of all inputs on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple jQuery price calculator, but it doesn't check if inputs are selected on page load.

It will see that Apple is checked after you click on Banana, but how to make it to check everything on start?

I've tried to add `ready` and `on load` before `function`, but it doesn't work for some reason.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.calculating').change(function () {
        var price = 0;
        $('.calculating').each(function(){
         if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
             price += parseInt($(this).attr("data-price"), 10);
            }
        })
        $(".price").text(price);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="apple" data-price="100" class="calculating" checked><label for="apple">Apple - 100$</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="banana" data-price="100" class="calculating"><label for="banana">Banana - 100$</label>
<br />
Total price: <span class="price">0</span>$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to trigger change event by adding `.change();` in the end of the code.
I guess it's the most simple solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.calculating').change(function () {
        var price = 0;
        $('.calculating').each(function(){
         if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
             price += parseInt($(this).attr("data-price"), 10);
            }
        })
        $(".price").text(price);
    }).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="apple" data-price="100" class="calculating" checked><label for="apple">Apple - 100$</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="banana" data-price="100" class="calculating"><label for="banana">Banana - 100$</label>
<br />
Total price: <span class="price">0</span>$
```

Answer (score 1):

Because event change did not call when document ready.

You should move code to calculate total to another function `calculateTotal` and call in both `ready` and `change` event as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      calculateTotal();
})

$('.calculating').change(function () {
        calculateTotal();
});

function calculateTotal(){
        var price = 0;
        $('.calculating').each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
             price += parseInt($(this).attr("data-price"), 10);
            }
        })
        $(".price").text(price);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      calculateTotal();
})

$('.calculating').change(function () {
        calculateTotal();
});
    
function calculateTotal(){
        var price = 0;
        $('.calculating').each(function(){
         if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
             price += parseInt($(this).attr("data-price"), 10);
            }
        })
        $(".price").text(price);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="apple" data-price="100" class="calculating" checked><label for="apple">Apple - 100$</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="banana" data-price="100" class="calculating"><label for="banana">Banana - 100$</label>
<br />
Total price: <span class="price">0</span>$
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I click in your snippet, nothing changes.

Comment: Yes, but now it's not a calculator anymore. If you click on Banana, nothing happens. But in the original code it adds up.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $(this).is(":checked") try $(this).prop('checked')